# Jquery ajax call not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create an ajax call, but it does not work, the link is not even disabled.

My Jquery:

```
$('table th a').click(function(e) {
                var a = $(this).closest('a');
                $.ajax({
                        type: GET,
                        url: a.attr('href'),
                        data: a.serialize(),
                        success:function(msg){
                $('#formcontent').html(msg);
                                }
return false
                });
```

Part of my HTML:

```
<div id="formcontent">
```

Navn
            Feature 1
              Feature 2
              Feature 3
              Feature 4
              Feature 5

```
</div>
```

Comment: There is not table for your tr.

Comment: There is I just took a part of my HTML to illustrate\

Comment: Try to use like this **var a = $(this)**. Because your adding click event to <a /> element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. "GET" (your `type` parameter), needs to be a string:

   ```
   type: "GET",
   ```
2. [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize) is for form elements, not anchor tags... what are you trying to achieve with it?
3. And one I missed (as pointed out by [ace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953806/jquery-ajax-call-not-working/6953908#6953908) in his answer), `return false;` in inside the AJAX call, not inside the click handler. (added for answer-completeness, not to steal anything away from ace!)

As for problems which won't *stop* the snippet working, but *should* be fixed:

1. `$(this).closest('a');` is completely redundant. Use `$(this)` instead.
2. Instead of binding handlers to numerous elements (lots of work!) bind it to a single element instead, using either [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live) or [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate)

   ```
   $('table').delegate('th a', 'click', function(e) {
       var a = $(this);
       $.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
           url: a.attr('href'),
           data: 'something',
           success: function(msg) {
               $('#formcontent').html(msg);
           }
           return false
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: I am just trying to creata a simple ajax call when the table th a link is clicked

Comment: @Rails: I understood that much... but what are you trying to achieve with `data: a.serialize(),`... what data do you want to send to the server?

Comment: I just want the information needed to ajax render the content where the link goes to

Comment: Now it works on the first click, but when clicking again it is a normal link

Comment: @Rails: If your `table` is a **descendant** of the `$('#formcontent')`, then you're replacing all the elements you bound the event handlers to with new ones; which is why the handlers are only firing first time round. If you're using the `delegate` method as-per my example, change the `$('table').delegate` to `$(''#formcontent').delegate`. If you're still using `$('table th a').click`, you'll have to rebind  the handlers again in your `success` callback (**after** adding the content to the `$('#formcontent')` element.

Answer (score 0):

Your `return false` is inside your ajax call, it should be like this

```
$('table th a').click(function(e) {
  var a = $(this).closest('a');
  $.ajax({
    type: GET,
    url: a.attr('href'),
    data: a.serialize(),
    success:function(msg){
      $('#formcontent').html(msg);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr><th><a name="first" href="content.html">Test</a></th><th><a href="content.html" name="second">Test</a></th><th><a name="third" href="content.html">Test</a></th></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
<div id="formcontent">
&nbsp;
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('table th a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();        
        var a = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: a.attr('href'), /*content.html*/
            data: a.serialize(),
            success: function(msg) {
                $('#formcontent').html(msg);   
            }
        });
    });

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use  **e.preventDefault();** to stop default navigation or else put return false after ajax function.

Comment: Use firebug or IE9 tool to trace Ajax calls.. I used for testing **Firebug**

Comment: The return false; only works if I but it outsite the succes and inside the ajax call

Comment: I still get the problem with it only works on the first click

Comment: @Railsbeginner let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2149/discussion-between-windows-phone-7-developer-and-rails-beginner)

Comment: Can you pls tell be what is the error your get.. in clear. Please check with current code..I checked in Diff browsers it's working fine here. Remember I just pointing to same page in my code. So, content won't change..

Comment: The error is that the Jquery does not work at the rendered content

Comment: Try to put msg in alert and check is it hold something to display?

Comment: You want to send Data then try to use like this data: { name: function() { return a.attr('name');}/*,.....*/ }